# Difference between Cross-Sectional and Nested Case-Control Samples in Cohort Studies

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, panel-data, descriptive-statistics, epidemiology

I have a question regarding the cross-sectional sample from the most recent visit and the nested case-control sample extracted from a cohort study, especially when the exposure of interest was collected at baseline.

Suppose the exposure of interest was collected at baseline and does not change over time. In this scenario, is the cross-sectional sample extracted from the most recent visit equivalent to the nested case-control study, given that the information on cases is the same?

If there are differences, do they primarily arise from the controls, since the nested case-control study requires matching with cases?

For example, let's say I have a longitudinal study of 1,000 people at baseline (assuming no losses to follow-up), with 5 follow-up visits, and at visit 5, I observe a total of 300 cases.

Cross-sectional sample: I extract the data directly from visit 5, resulting in 300 cases versus 700 controls.

Nested case-control study: I use the 300 cases and match them with similar controls without conditions, so not all 700 controls are used.

Are these the main differences between the cross-sectional sample from the most recent visit and the nested case-control sample extracted from a cohort study?

Comment: What is your cross-sectional analysis? Comparing 300 cases to the 700 controls will not in general give the same result as the 300 cases compared to 300 matched controls. For instance say the first 300 of the 700 controls are "close matches" (same age, gender, genetic make-up etc) with the 300 cases and the remaining 400 controls are very different, then the cross-sectional comparison will be confounded by lots of these differences but the case-control will not.